# How can I make this SQL sort by most relevent?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have what appears to be a working set of SQL statements, which operate on a drop-down scenario. The first is an all-inclusive AND, where every requested option is matched. Failing that, it goes to the second sql call which is based on OR's.

Can someone please explain to me or provide better statements where the second tier OR scenario is sorted by most relevent first, meaning the most options are matched as the first entries and going downwards from there?

Or, alternately, if you have a better method of handling this search, possibly with a single call, that would be even better.

The first SQL call based on AND:

```
SELECT 
    l.id,l.title,l.city 
FROM listings l 
JOIN listings_facilities_xref x ON l.id = x.listing_id 
WHERE l.property_type = '1' 
    AND x.facility_id = '1' 
    AND x.facility_id = '8' 
    AND x.facility_id = '54' 
    AND x.facility_id = '11' 
    AND l.city = 'Orlando' 
    AND l.state = '16' 
GROUP BY l.id
```

The second tier call based on OR:

```
SELECT l.id,l.title,l.city 
FROM listings l 
JOIN listings_facilities_xref x ON l.id = x.listing_id 
WHERE l.property_type = '1' 
AND (
    x.facility_id = '1' 
    OR x.facility_id = '8' 
    OR x.facility_id = '54' 
    OR x.facility_id = '11'
) 
AND l.city = 'Orlando' 
AND l.state = '16' 
GROUP BY l.id
```

My table layout is as follows:

```
mysql> describe listings;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(12)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| owner_id      | int(12)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| property_type | int(12)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title         | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description   | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| yearbuilt     | int(12)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| beds          | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| baths         | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sleeps        | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sqfeet        | int(12)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lotsize       | int(12)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address1      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address2      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| city          | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| state         | int(12)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| zipcode       | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| latitude      | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| longitude     | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created       | int(12)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated       | int(12)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe listings_facilities_xref;
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(12) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| listing_id  | int(12) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| facility_id | int(12) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| category_id | int(12) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Sample Import Data can be found at:

listings:  https://pastebin.com/EeuaEFrR

listings_facilities_xref: https://pastebin.com/7WeHgEaE

Comment: Your version with the `AND` will never return any rows.

Comment: The first query will fail always. There is no single row which is going to have facility_id as 1 and 11 and 5..

Comment: Gordon, Valli: I see that now thanks. Too many hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want:

```
SELECT l.id, l.title, l.city 
FROM listings l 
JOIN listings_facilities_xref x ON l.id = x.listing_id 
WHERE l.property_type = 1 AND
      x.facility_id IN (1, 8, 54, 11) AND
      l.city = 'Orlando' AND
      l.state = 16 
GROUP BY l.id, l.title, l.city
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```